# How to filter a date in Excel using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below, I denoted that I need to filter the date by using 'Tested on' column, but I couldn't get the correct result.

And Date's datatype is Date-Time

```
df = msft[msft.Tested On == '2018-01-11']
```

But I am getting an error on this code:

```
msft['Tested On']dt.date
```

Comment: `df = msft[msft['Tested On'] == '2018-01-11']`

Comment: need `[]` instead `.`, because not one word column name

Comment: But i'm getting error on this code msft['Tested On']dt.date

Comment: `msft['Tested On'].dt.date` ? Or `pd.to_datetime(msft['Tested On']).dt.date` ?

Comment: Thanks bro for  your instant help

Comment: To formulate question do not use blockquote, please.

Comment: I don't know how to edit ? What I supposed to use for questions